# when I input an invalid triangle but the code does not give me the expected result

Tags: if-statement

> when I enter an invalid triangle to test my if statements , it shows
> me the result of scalene triangle
> this is my code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] integers = new int[3] ; `to store the values of the triangle sides`



    
    
    System.out.print("Enter length of each side of the triangle:");
```

> when I enter values 100 5 7 , it shows me the result of scalene triangle

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){                    
        integers[i] = sc.nextInt();            
    }
    
    if ( (integers[0]+integers[2]>integers[1] || integers[2]+integers[1]>integers[0] || integers[1]+integers[0]>integers[2]) ) {
        if ( integers[0] == integers[1] && integers[1] == integers[2]) {
            System.out.println("Triangle is equilateral") ;
        }
        
        else if ( integers[0] == integers[1] || integers[0] == integers[2] || integers[1] == integers[2]) {
            System.out.println("Triangle is isosceles");
        }
        
        else  {
            System.out.println("Triangle is scalene");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not a triangle"); **this is the problem**
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are asking if that is a triangle(in the first if statement) you should use an and instead of an or operator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).